# Joining tables back to themselves in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, data-modeling

Let's say I have three tables:

`user` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`location` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and `document` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `maintainer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I can successfully pull the user info and it's corresponding `location` and `document` info with the following query:

```
SELECT * from `user` LEFT JOIN `location` on user.loc = location.id LEFT JOIN `document` on user.doc = document.id;
```

The `location` info is easily referenced as its information doesn't refer to any other rows in any other tables. The `document` table, however, contains a `maintainer` field which directly corresponds back to another `user` in the `user` table. This field encapsulates the `user` information, and does not give me actual `user` data.

Is there not a way of querying the tables such that the data for the `maintainer` returns the actual `user` data as opposed to an `id`?

Comment: The general idea behind self joins is to use a different alias each time you reference the table.

Comment: @DanBracuk care to elaborate? I'm not particularly versed in SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    u.name as user_name,
    m.name as maintainer_name,
    l.name as location_name
from user as u
    left outer join document as d on d.id = u.doc
    left outer join user as m on m.id = d.maintainer
    left outer join location as l on l.id = u.loc
```